# mvc4 validation of partial view form

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following data model:

```
public class Training
{
    public Training()
    {
        this.ID = 0;
        this.Name = null;
        this.Instructor = null;
        this.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.Time = null;
        this.Duration = null;
    }

    public Training(int id, string name, string instructor, DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string time, string duration)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Instructor = instructor;
        this.StartDate = startdate;
        this.EndDate = enddate;
        this.Time = time;
        this.Duration = duration;
    }

    public Training(int id, string instructor)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Instructor = instructor;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following partial view called "CreatePartialView.cshtml"

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Training Name</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="trainingname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Instructor Name</td>
    <td>
        <select id="selectInstructor">
           <option selected="selected">Select Instructor</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Select Time</td>
    <td>
        <input id="timepicker" />

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>
        <input id="startdatepicker" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>
        <input id="enddatepicker" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Duration</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="duration" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit-button" class="btnStyleOne" />

    </td>
</tr>
```

and i have de follwing code

```
$("#submit-button").click(function () {
// On submit button click close dialog box
$("#createForm").dialog("close");

//Set inserted values
var name = $("#trainingname").val();
var selectInstructor = $("#selectInstructor").val();
var startdatepicker = $("#startdatepicker").val();
var enddatepicker = $("#enddatepicker").val();
var timepicker = $("#timepicker").val();
var duration = $("#duration").val();

// Call Create action method
$.post('/Home/Create', { "name": name, 
"instructor": selectInstructor, "startdate": startdatepicker, 
                         "enddate": enddatepicker, 
                         "time": timepicker, "duration": duration },
    function () {
        alert("data is posted successfully");
        window.location.reload(true);

     });
```

In HomeController, we call InsertTraining() method of repository to save data in database.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Create(Training training)
{
_trainingRepository.InsertTraining(training);
```

}

and before cilcking on submit-button i must validate the form of CreatePartialview.cshtml ,how can I do it?

Comment: You need to create a partial view with a strongly typed viewmodel with validation attributes. This way you can use the standard Razor html helpers as well (`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`) and you can add server-side/client-side validation to this model and validation messages to your view.

Comment: thanks for your ansower,but here i dont know how to validate a form without using a strongly typed viewmodel , ara there other solution for my case, i need more explaine :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's a lot of things you haven't covered on your project or have not specified in your question. The answer would be too long and I would suggest to read a tutorial and then come back with any more specific questions. Read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.100).aspx